# Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.0.0 debug mode error

Tags: cdn, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I have two questions, one about a bug and one about cdn

**QUESTION 1: (BUG)**

I have just added the new NuGet package:  Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.0.0.
I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, and everything seems to be working except for one major bug.

If I use **debug="true"** in web.config, then no script tags ever get outputted. I checked the view source and there are no  tags for that bundle at all.

If I set **debug="false"** then I get the script tag that points to my minification file.

***Is this a bug? Has anyone else experienced that? ***

As a workaround so that I'm at least able to debug my application, I forced optimization on regardless if I'm in debug mode or not BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

**QUESTION 2: (CDN)**

Also another question I have is about the CDN Support:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", 
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

If I want to add another script with CDN support, then I would have to add another bundle, therefore if UseCdn="false", then it will try and load up 2 scripts separately, meaning 2 requests. Is there any way to have CDN support for multiple scripts so that it will combine them into 1 request if UseCdn="false"?

Something like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/multiple").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js", jqueryCdnPath,
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js", jqueryUICdnPath,
));
```

Regards DotnetShadow

Comment: I'm sure you're up and running with MVC 3 and Web Optimization by now but if it helps I wrote a blog post demonstrating how to get started with this: http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/using-web-optimization-with-mvc-3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you expand on what isn't working on in your MVC3 app, i.e. how are you using the Scripts/Styles.Render methods?

In regards to #2, currently the CDN support is only on a per bundle basis.  So you will not be able to do the conditional bundling that you want and use cdn (unless you had access to a CDN which you could upload new content to, then you could just upload your bundle to the CDN)

Comment: If I set debug="true" in web.config the no script tags are outputted

i.e. there is no
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

Instead in the source where the above script should be it's blank.

I'm using @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jsminify") and my bundle is:
// JS custom bundle
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/jsminify").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.custom.min.js"
            ));

Comment: Ah, so the default convention will ignore *.min.js in debug mode, since those are minified files.  You can clear the ignore list, but its probably easiest just to rename the files to not be .min.js.

Comment: I don't think that's how it's meant to work at all, I just gave a trivial example but I'm sure if I had non .min files the same thing will happen. I will test it out later. Is there any documentation that shows that it will ignore .min.js files in debug mode?

Comment: Well I wrote the feature, so I'm pretty sure its ignoring *.min.js in debug mode :)  The best docs currently are here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: I guess I thought the rule should be if debug=true, don't do minifications but at the very least output the files listed in the bundle. I mean it will be confusing if you have a mixture of min files and non min files and suddenly in debug mode some scripts will output while others won't. 
Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the docs, I think this clears it up:
    Selecting “.min” file for release when “FileX.min.js” and “FileX.js” exist.
    Selecting the non “.min” version for debug.
    Ignoring “-vsdoc” files (such as jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js), which are used only by IntelliSense.

I guess the case I'm making is when we don't have both a min and non min file for the one script, is the rule that will just ignore that file?

Comment: Yeah that's currently the default behavior, it will always ignore .min files when debug=true.  Lots of people have been hitting this issue, so we are looking at ways to make this issue less painful...

Comment: @HaoKung are the cdns ignored if its set on debug=true ? cause all my cdn links are not in the layout.