# Styles.Render/Scripts.Render does not render in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using bundling and minification with MVC 3 with .NET Framework 4. Created *BundleConfig.cs* and placed under `App_Data` folder.
Called `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` from `Application_Start()` of *Global.asax* file.
From master file I called

```
<% Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base"); %>
<% Scripts.Render("~/Scripts","~/Scripts/Controllers","~/Scripts/Views");%>
```

on header tag.
However CSS not rendered as expected and jQuery not recognized as `Scripts.Render` does not work as expected.

My *BundleConfig.cs* class definition follows here...

```
 public class BundleConfig
 {
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base").Include(
            "~/Content/themes/base/Blueprint-Liquid.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/ex.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/exNav.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/ie.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.qtip.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/reset.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/Site.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/structure-fixed.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/structure-fluid.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/tipsy.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/typography.css",
            "~/Content/themes/base/ui.jqgrid.css")
        );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Controllers").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Controllers/ProjectController.js",
            "~/Scripts/Controllers/RequestController.js",
            "~/Scripts/Controllers/SystemController.js")
        );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Views").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Views/ProjectView.js",
            "~/Scripts/Views/RequestView.js",
            "~/Scripts/Views/SystemView.js")
        );

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts").Include(
              "~/Scripts/Dialog.js",
              "~/Scripts/EX.Computing.js",
              "~/Scripts/exNav.js",
              "~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.fluid.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.qtip.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.tipsy.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.jquery.validate-vsdoc.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
              "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
              "~/Scripts/json2.js",
              "~/Scripts/Labels.js",
              "~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.js",
              "~/Scripts/SessionTimeOut.js",
              "~/Scripts/underscore.js")
       );

       BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; 
   }
```

I am wondering what I am missing? Any help grately appreciated!

Thanks,
Ramani

Comment: define "as expected".  How DOES it work if it's not working as expected?

Comment: Before using bundling and minification my web page used to render properly with all conrols aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started using Bundling and Minification I am not sure whether it works with MVC3, and 
   found it works without any issues. I thought of sharing my code here so that it helps someone.

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Ex.Computing
{
  public class BundleConfig
  {
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
         bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(

                        "~/Content/themes/base/reset.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/Blueprint-Liquid.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/typography.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/eXNav.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/structure-fluid.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/eX.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/ui.jqgrid.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/Site.css",
                        "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.qtip.css"



                       )
                 ); 


         bundles.GetBundleFor("~/Content/themes/base/css").Orderer = new AppCssOrderer();


         var bootstrapOrdering = new BundleFileSetOrdering("bootstrap");

         bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/js").Include(
             "~/Scripts/eXNav.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1-vsdoc.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js",
             "~/Scripts/Labels.js",
             "~/Scripts/Dialog.js",
             "~/Scripts/SessionTimeOut.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.qtip.js",
             "~/Scripts/json2.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.watermark.min.js",
             "~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.src.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.fluid.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
             "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
             "~/Scripts/Computing.js",
             "~/Scripts/Controllers/ProjectController.js",
             "~/Scripts/Controllers/RequestController.js",
             "~/Scripts/Controllers/SystemController.js",
             "~/Scripts/Views/ProjectView.js",
             "~/Scripts/Views/RequestView.js",
             "~/Scripts/Views/SystemView.js"

              )
        );

         bundles.GetBundleFor("~/Scripts/js").Orderer = new AppJsOrderer();

         BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; 

      }
  }

  public class AppCssOrderer : IBundleOrderer 
  { 
    public IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> OrderFiles(BundleContext context,   
    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> files)
    { 
       // return files.OrderBy(f => f.Name == "eyNav.css" ? -1 : 1); 
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        if (files == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("files");

        return files;
    }
  }

  public class AppJsOrderer : IBundleOrderer
  {
    public IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, 
    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> files)
    {
        // return files.OrderBy(f => f.Name == "eyNav.css" ? -1 : 1); 
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        if (files == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("files");

        return files;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve issue with `debug='true'` and removing `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to our club: [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.0.0 debug mode error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000935/microsoft-asp-net-web-optimization-framework-1-0-0-debug-mode-error/12402214#12402214)

I fix this with next code, but I don't like this solution:

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: that does not work. I do not see CSS applied to my site at all and see jQuery not defined errors.I have changed order of CSS and Js files the way my views referencing them but it does not have any affect.

Comment: @user1358784 why are you using bundle names (paths) equal as real folders on server? Look this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: I cleacred above issue by changing render methods to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= @BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/themes/base")%>" /> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= @BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts")%>" ></script>  However now I am experiencing resource not found erros(404) for both CSS and JS files.I am using server folder structure as bundle names.

Comment: @user1358784 if you write `~/Scripts/mybundle` instead `~/Scripts`, this will be `Scripts` folder with unique path.

Comment: yes,it worked with your suggestion.I am able to implement bundling and minimification with MVC 3 using system.web.optimization assembly.

Comment: @user1358784 If you remove `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` and in `web.config` set `debug=true` what result do you have? it must generate separate files, but it doesn't...

Comment: Yes it does not generate separate files!