# How to make fake paths for resources in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc3. I have two script files on my web site like these:

```
<script type="text/jscript" src="/SiteName/lib/jquery/menus.js"></script>

<script type="text/jscript" src="/SiteName/lib/jquery/dialogs.js"></script>
```

These are real paths for these two .js files where the SiteName directory is on the root of my website.
Now when the site rendered, i want to be these pathes like:

```
<script type="text/jscript" src="/lib/jquery/menus.js"></script>

<script type="text/jscript" src="/lib/jquery/dialogs.js"></script>
```

As a result, the "SiteName" portion is deleted from the path! but really it is available!
Yet the browser must be able to load these scripts.
I think this must be done by routes.MapRoute or like these!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **BundleConfig** to achieve this. You can create styles and script bundles that have a virtual path with the added benefit of minification. If you add multiple scripts into one bundle, it'll join and minify both into one virtual script. e.g.:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/lib/jquery").Include(
             "~/SiteName/lib/jquery/menus.js",
             "~/SiteName/lib/jquery/dialogs.js"));
```

On page render, it'll show up as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery"></script>
```

From memory this wasn't there by default in MVC3, but it looks pretty easy to implement if you refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12754108/769083