# What's the bundling and minification tool used by ASP.net MVC4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, google-closure-compiler

ASP.net MVC4 provides bundling and minification functionalities to combine and compress JS files. May I know what's the engine behind it? Is it a public engine or a new engine implemented by ASP.net MVC itself? I am analyzing the need of adding Google closure compiler to my JS code, but it seems ASP.net MVC4 bundling and minification are doing a similar job to Google closure compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundling and minification in MVC 4 is a Nuget package: [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.0.0](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.0.0). You can look on dependencies at `nuget.org`, ask questions to **Hao Kung** as he is one of the developers ( [Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.0.0 debug mode error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000935/microsoft-asp-net-web-optimization-framework-1-0-0-debug-mode-error) ). In future it will be open source.